# How to show multiple camera previews in one activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

> ```
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     mCamera = getCameraInstance();
>     context = getApplicationContext();
>     // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
>     mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
>     FrameLayout preview1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview1);
>     FrameLayout preview2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview2);
>     //preview.setRotation(-90);
>     preview1.addView(mPreview);
>     preview2.addView(mPreview);
> ```
>
> This is what I have tried to do. In above snippet if I use just one
>   FrameLayout , it works fine.Like this:
>
> ```
>     mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
>     FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
>     //preview.setRotation(-90);
>     preview1.addView(mPreview);
> ```
>
> Correspondingly, the layout looks like this:
>
> ```
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/camera_preview1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="1">
> </FrameLayout>
>
> <FrameLayout
>      android:id="@+id/camera_preview2"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="1">
> </FrameLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/speedBackgound"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="80dp"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/lastPic"
>         android:layout_width="70dp"
>         android:layout_height="70dp"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:id="@+id/button_capture"
>         android:layout_width="80dp"
>         android:layout_height="80dp"
>         android:onClick="takePhoto"
>         android:layout_gravity="right"/>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> In case of single frame, it works fine.  When two frames and previews
>   are added I get a runtime error:
>
> `The specified child already has a parent.  You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.`

Any ideas to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hey @androxpa you achived solution of your problem..if yes then Please Help me..my question is here.........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to create several `SurfaceTexture` and pass them in the method `createCaptureSession` of `Camera` object.

Comment: Hey @Omar Aflak..Please tell me if you know the Solution.please your any type of help appreciated...my question is here if you really know then tell me..PLEASE......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview